# Non-Noetherian subring of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals, noetherian

I'm trying to understand the proof to the following problem.

> Give an example of a non-Noetherian subring of $\mathbb{C}[X, Y] .$

> Proof:  Consider the subring $R$ of $\mathbb{C}[X, Y]$ generated (over $\mathbb{C})$ by $X, X Y, X Y^{2}, X Y^{3}, \ldots$. This has a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ given by the kernel of the ring homomorphism $\phi : R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ taking $X$ and $Y$ to zero. Note that this ideal is generated by the monomials $X$ $X Y, X Y^{2},$ etc. It can be shown that if $f$ is in this ideal, then every monomial of $f$ is in this ideal. Thus if this ideal is finitely generated, it is generated by a finite set of monomials (namely, all the monomials appearing in the given finite set of generators). So suppose $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by a finite set of monomials $c_{i} X^{a_{i}} Y^{b_{i}},$ and let $b$ be larger than all of the $b_{i} .$ Then $X Y^{b}$ cannot lie in $\mathfrak{m},$ which is a contradiction.

I had some questions. Partial answers (answering only a few of the questions) are very welcome! (I will upvote them too)

1. Firstly, we know from the first isomorphism theorem that $R / \text{Ker}(\phi) \cong \text{Im}(\phi) \subset \mathbb{C}$. But how can I know that $\text{Im}(\phi)$ is a field to conclude $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal? Also, isn't $\text{Im}(\phi) = 0$? $R$ is generated by $X, X Y, X Y^{2}, X Y^{3}, \ldots$, and $\phi(X\times Y^n) = \phi(X)\times \phi(Y)^n = 0$ as $\phi$ sends $X,Y$ to $0$. So for any element of $R$, $\phi$ sends it to $0$?
2. I don't understand how we are using that $\mathfrak{m}$ is maximal.
3. Am I right to think that the reason why $X Y^{b}$ cannot lie in $\mathfrak{m}$ is because  $R$ is generated by $X, X Y, X Y^{2}, X Y^{3}, \ldots$, thus for a higher power of $Y$ than $b_i$ to be in $\mathfrak{m}$, it must be divisible by $X^2$?
4. How can we show that "if $f$ is in this ideal, then every monomial of $f$ is in this ideal"?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: For 1.: What is the image of the constant polynomials in $R$ under $\phi$?

Comment: 4. This is a general fact: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_ideal

Comment: @leoli1 One answer seems to specify that it is the identity on the constant polynomials of $R$, but I don't understand why this is. Also, does $R$ even have constant polynomials in it? I think every element of $R$ is at least divisible by $X$.

Comment: 2. A ring R is Noetherian iff every ideal of R is finitely generated. My guess is that it is convenient to take a maximal ideal and check if it is finitely generated.