# What does a generated ring look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

The motivation for this question comes from one of my previous posts: [Non-Noetherian subring of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970045/non-noetherian-subring-of-mathbbcx-y/3970104#3970104). There, I encounter the following statement,

> Consider the subring $R$ of $\mathbb{C}[X, Y]$ generated (over $\mathbb{C})$ by $X, X Y, X Y^{2}, X Y^{3}, \ldots$.

My question is, what does it mean to 'generate a ring' in that context? Usually, when I was given a set $S \subset K$ where $K$ is a ring, and I needed to generate a ring with $S$, I would do: Generated Ring $= \{\sum_{i=1}^n s_i k_i:$ $n$ is finite, $s_i \in S$ and $k_i \in K \}$.

But in the above statement, the context in which it appears makes it clear that $\mathbb{C} \subset R$. So the previous notion I was taught doesn't work, as $X$ does not divide every element of $\mathbb{C}$. What does the ring $R$ of $\mathbb{C}[X, Y]$ generated (over $\mathbb{C})$ by $X, X Y, X Y^{2}, X Y^{3}, \ldots$ even look like? What does it mean to generate such a ring?

I've read somewhere that this has to do with the notion of an 'Algebra'. But I've never heard of an Algebra, not in this context anyway, and googling shows that Algebra is a concept that shows up in Commutative Algebra, not in an elementary UG Algebra course like the one I'm taking now. So I'm fairly certain that this can be understood without referring to the notion of an Algebra.

Comment: It's probably the smallest subring of $\mathbb C[X,Y]$ which contains both $\mathbb C$ and the generators.

Comment: Hmm, is there an easy way I can visualize such set? @Vercassivelaunos Also, how can I deduce that it is the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ that contains $\mathbb{C}$ in the first place? (From 'definitions', and not 'deducing from context' as I have done in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description of what it means to generate a subring is incorrect; you've described generating an ideal. If $S$ is a subset of a commutative ring $R$, the subring of $R$ generated by $S$ consists of polynomials in the elements of $S$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Explicitly, these consist of sums (with integer coefficients) of monomials $s_1^{e_1} s_2^{e_2} \dots s_k^{e_k}$ where $s_i \in S$ and $e_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. This is the intersection of all subrings of $R$ containing $S$.

"Generated over $\mathbb{C}$" means that $R$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra (a ring which is also a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ such that multiplication is $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear) and we consider sums of monomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. This is the intersection of all $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebras of $R$ containing $S$ (a $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra being a subring closed under scalar multiplication by $\mathbb{C}$). So the $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{C}[X, Y]$ generated by $X, XY, XY^2, XY^3$ consists of $\mathbb{C}$-linear combinations of monomials in $X, XY, XY^2, \dots$, of the form

$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (XY^i)^{e_i}.$$

It's then a straightforward exercise to show that the monomials $X^i Y^j$ which occur in this way are exactly the monomials such that $i \neq 0$. In other words, $R$ can equivalently be described as the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of the ideal $(X)$ and the identity $1$.